# Can we set quota limit on cognitive services API calls ?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I was just wondering whether it is possible to set limit on number calls in Cognitive Services - this is in context with - keeping API keys in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is not a way to set limits or caps for your quota at this time.  If you are subscribed to a paid subscription through Azure you are able to monitor your monthly usage.

This information appears when you are viewing the resource item (your subscription) in Azure.